# JavaScript `this` in event listener when using classes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple Game of Life app. Unfortunately, after wrapping my code with a class, I've encountered the following problem.

```
cell.addEventListener('click', this.cellClick.bind(this));
```

I've binded the `cellClick()` method, but when I try to use `this.id.split()` or `this.className` within the `cellClick()` method I get an uncaught exception `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at GOL.cellClick`.

I've tried to use an arrow function instead, but that didn't work too.

The code works when I don't use classes.

I'm fairly new to JS and I've tried to look for a solution online and couldn't find one.

```
class GOL {
    constructor(rows, columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;

        this.currentGeneration = Array(this.rows).fill(false).map(() => Array(this.columns).fill(0));
        this.nextGeneration = Array(this.rows).fill(false).map(() => Array(this.columns).fill(0));
    }

    createWorld() {
        const world = document.getElementById('world');
        const table = document.createElement('table');

        table.setAttribute('id', 'grid');

        for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
            const tr = document.createElement('tr');

            for (let j = 0; j < this.columns; j++) {
                const cell = document.createElement('td');
                cell.setAttribute('id', i + ':' + j);
                cell.setAttribute('class', 'dead');
                cell.addEventListener('click', this.cellClick.bind(this));

                tr.appendChild(cell);
            }

            table.appendChild(tr);
        }

        world.appendChild(table);
    }

    cellClick() {
        const location = this.id.split(':');
        const row = location.indexOf(0);
        const column = location.indexOf(1);

        this.className === 'alive' ? this.setAttribute('class', 'dead') : this.setAttribute('class', 'alive');
    }
}
```

Comment: Add these 2 lines into your constructor `this.createWorld = this.createWorld.bind(this);
this.cellClick = this.cellClick.bind(this);`

Comment: it is not related to binding, but just the id of the object is nothing

Comment: The binding is what is messing this up. From what I can tell, OP is expecting `this` to be a reference to the clicked element, in which case the `.bind` is actually what is preventing the correct behavior. OP, if you try this with the `.bind` call removed, does it work as expected?

Comment: Indeed, as CRice says. You want to have the `this` that is passed to the event handler, so just use: `cell.addEventListener('click', this.cellClick);`. I think it is very confusing that you want a different `this` in `cellClick`, than the object of which it is a property. It would be better to move the `cellClick` out of `GOL`, as it does not use any of its instance properties.

Comment: your object don't have id property that's why it through this error. and here you don't need  to use bind method. bind method we generally used for callbacks

Comment: Alternatively, use `event.target`.

Comment: Okay, it's working now. The bind was messing it. Without the binding it works, but my IDE is unhappy about `id`, `className`, and `setAttribute` references in the `cellClick()` method, so I've moved it out of the class. Thanks for your help.